# Изменения объектов в бесконечном цикле по ходу цикла: обновление величины по времени в игре

Tags: python, разработка-игр

Недавно начал изучать питон, есть задумка сделать крайне примитивную игру.
Для накопления ресурса - золото с последующим постепенным увеличением, использую функцию с бесконечным циклом.

```
import time

current_gold = 100
def gold(current_gold):
    while True:
        print(current_gold)
        time.sleep(1)
        current_gold += 10

gold(current_gold)
current_gold -= 50  # test
current_gold -= 50  # test
```

Как мне в реальном времени менять `current_gold`? Тут нужно все загонять в класс или нужна еще одна функция, которая будет ссылаться на существующую `gold(current_gold)` только с аргументом `gold(current_gold - 100)` или как лучше реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше реализовать без цикла, т.к. это дополнительные расходы. У Вас скорее всего есть время начала накопления ресурса:

```
import time

user_start = time.time()  # Время unixtime когда пользователь начал накапливать ресурс
```

Теперь при обращении к объекту пользователя Вы считаете в реальном времени:

```
new_balance = (time.time() - user_start) * 10
```

И возвращаете кол-во ресурса за пройденное время, вот класс, который это реализует:

```
import time

class GoldInGame(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_time = int(time.time())
        self.my_gold = 0
        self.gold_in_sec = 1  # количество золота в секунду

    def now_my_gold(self):
        now = int(time.time())
        self.my_gold += (now - self.start_time) * self.gold_in_sec
        self.start_time = now
        return self.my_gold

    def upgrade_user(self, point):
        self.gold_in_sec += point
        print('now my gold in sec', self.gold_in_sec)
        self.start_time = int(time.time())
        return True

user_gold = GoldInGame()
time.sleep(2)
now = user_gold.now_my_gold()
print(now)
user_gold.upgrade_user(1)
time.sleep(2)
now = user_gold.now_my_gold()
print(now)
user_gold.upgrade_user(1)
time.sleep(2)
now = user_gold.now_my_gold()
print(now)
time.sleep(10)
now = user_gold.now_my_gold()
print(now)
time.sleep(2)
now = user_gold.now_my_gold()
print(now)
```

Comment: так получается, если мне нужно изменение переменной каждую секунду, то в любом случае придется этот код в цикл загонять.

Comment: Не нужен тут цикл, зачем переменную изменять каждую секунду?

Comment: Самая близкая аналогия - мне нужен счетчик(секундомер), к которому можно прибавлять секунды и отнимать в любой момент времени, а так же уменьшать и увеличивать интервал "тиков". Насколько я понял метод с time.time не совсем подходит для мониторинга значения переменной. К примеру, у меня должно копиться 2 золота каждую секунду.Я строю ферму, которая стоит 50 золота, после чего уже добывается 3 золота/сек.

Comment: Для того, чтобы отнять зоолото, просто отнимите его от `self.my_gold`

Comment: @Павел: полезно ввести "игровое время", не привязанное к часам  компьютера (`time.monotonic()`). Для игр можно использовать асинхронную организацию программы (как в сетевых сервисах, GUI) -- есть *один* центральный цикл, в котором события обрабатываются и который предоставляет интерфейс, чтобы свои обработчики подключить (примером являются практически все популярные GUI, сетевые библиотеки). Центральный цикл может выглядеть как: `while not game_over: paint(); get_input(); handle_schedule_events(); compute_new_game_state()` (цикл может быть спрятан внутри библиотек, к примеру, tkinter, asyncio)